# How to make a local constructor variable into a member

Tags: f#

I create a timer in a constructor and want to make the timer a member of the constructed class. Since the timer isn't referenced by any other class member, it's compiled into a variable that is local to the constructor and hence garbage collected and killed.

One way of preventing this from happening is to make a dummy reference, like

```
type MyClass() as o =
    let timer = new Timer((fun _ -> o.Tick()), null, 0, 1000)

    member private o.DummyRef = timer
    member o.Tick() = printfn "Tick!"
```

Is there a neater way of forcing `timer` into becoming a member?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want it to be a member then `let` is the wrong tool for the job, since, [according to the spec](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/cambridge/projects/fsharp/manual/spec.html#_Toc335818937), the compiled form (local variable or field) is determined by the compiler. You probably want a private property:

```
type MyClass() as o =
    member val private Timer = new Timer((fun _ -> o.Tick()), null, 0, 1000)
```

Comment: Thx! `member` is the magical word I was looking for. I was considering the `val timer : Timer` syntax but then I'd have to use [<DefaultValue>], make it mutable and assign it in a ctor do block.

Answer (score 1):

Because you don't use `timer` anywhere, it is being optimized to a constructor local. If you were to use it somewhere else in your type definition then it would be compiled as a field of the class. e.g.

```
type MyClass() as o =
    let timer = new Timer((fun _ -> o.Tick()), null, 0, 1000)

    member o.Tick() = printfn "Tick"

    interface IDisposable with
        member x.Dispose() = timer.Dispose()
```

Comment: I know. I already wrote all that in the question. BTW, the code in the question *does* use timer elsewhere.

Comment: Yes, but you were using it only to force the compiler to do what you want. I was just suggesting that in a more complete type definition you probably wouldn't have to worry about it.